# How do we formulate time-reversal symmetry in the path-integral formalism?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, time-reversal-symmetry

In path-integral formalism, ordinary symmetries can just be implemented as transformations of fields, which are integral variables.

But time-reversal symmetry is antiunitary, and composed of a ordinary transformation and a complex-conjugate transformation. How can we implement complex conjugation in the path-integral formalism.